# DataSet from xsd generates xml with orphan children

Tags: xml, xsd, dataset, orphan

My requirement is to load generate a xml files based on an xsd and a group of queries asociated to the different nodes in the xsd. 
It also requires to page the data so the xml is split in multiple files but keeping the integrity of the top nodes (I mean the next level after the root).
My approach was to load a dataset with the data. If not paging is need all is ok, but when paging is included I get orphan nodes for all the levels below the top node. I thought the dataset, having all the relationships would prevent orphan rows.
Is there a way to make sure the result has no orphan children?

this is my the extrac of my code:

```
for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++)
{
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSetSchema.Tables)
    {
        if (dataTable.TableName == releasedOutput.PartitionNode)
        {
            var pagedSql = @"WITH pagingOutputSchema As ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY idnkey) as RowNumber, idnkey FROM {0} )
SELECT *
FROM {0} INNER JOIN
pagingOutputSchema ON {0}.idnkey = pagingOutputSchema.idnkey
WHERE pagingOutputSchema.RowNumber BETWEEN ({1} - 1) * {2} + 1  AND {1} * {2} 
ORDER BY 1".FormatWith(tmpFullTableName, page, rowsPerPage);
            _schemaXMLHandler.FillTableInDataSet(releasedOutput.Prefix, pagedSql, dataSetSchema, partitionNode);
        }
        else
        {
            var node = nodes.GetNodeByName(dataTable.TableName);
            _schemaXMLHandler.FillTableInDataSet(releasedOutput.Prefix, node.Sql, dataSetSchema, node);
        }
    }
    //this saves the loaded schema into a file
    var dstFileName = fileNamePre + "_part_" + (fileIndex) + ".xml";
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(dstFileName))
        dataSetSchema.WriteXml(fileStream);

    fileIndex++;
}
```